# Enable port 443 for ssh connection

Tags: ssh

I am trying to setup ssh on my port 443 but unfortunately I am not able to do it.

Here are the things I tried.

1. Set up the remote daemon running sshd on port 443 and restarted sshd
   service.

   ```
   sshd -p 443
   ```
2. I edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and added the below line
   and restarted the sshd service.

   ```
   Port 443
   ```

Now, even after performing the above steps in the remote machine, if I try and connect to port 443 of my remote machine, I couldn't connect. This is what happens when I try to connect my remote machine.

```
ssh -v -p 443 ramesh@192.168.104.167
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.104.167 [192.168.104.167] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.104.167 port 443: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.104.167 port 443: Connection refused
```

Is there some step that am missing? How could I enable port 443 to accept ssh connections so that I could achieve [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166503/run-a-local-socks-proxy-tunneled-through-ssh)?

**EDIT**

The output of `netstat --inet --inet6 -ln` command is as below.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41138           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN    
tcp6       0      0 :::51578                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: There's a firewall in the way. Does it work from localhost? Take it from there.

Comment: @Gilles, I have stopped the firewall in the remote machine but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `netstat --inet --inet6 -ln`?

Comment: The firewall can be anywhere in the line, from your ISP, to the other side ISP. BTW, are you able to access it from the standard port?

Comment: @Ramesh Can you please check remote machine `iptables -vnL | grep "443"` ? It could be blocked.

Comment: The firewall could be anywhere in between. Does it work from localhost?

Comment: So if the `netstat` has been run on the system which you want to connect to (the one with `sshd`) then forget the firewall hints. For whatever reason: `sshd` is not running at all. Check the logs.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, thanks for the pointer. If I change the port to 22, I could see an entry listed in the remote machine for `netstat` command output. So, if I change it to port 443, I guess it is being ignored.

Comment: @Simply_Me, It doesn't give me anything. I even disabled the firewall completely on this remote machine.

Comment: @Ramesh that means it needs to be updated. Now try it w/port 22 for example (the one you use to ssh).

Comment: @Simply_Me, I have disabled the firewall itself. So, I guess that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Maybe an LSM (SELinux, AppArmor) is active which kills sshd when it tries to bind to ports different from 22.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, thanks. That was it. I disabled `selinux` and tried. Now, I am getting **No route to host** error which is irrelevant to this question. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a daemon is configured to a non-standard port, started but does not appear in the `netstat` listing, then the reason may be that an active LSM (Linux Security Module) like SELinux or AppArmor forbids the daemon to bind to that port.

So check whether such a feature is active. If so then deactivate it for testing, and if that solves the problem then reconfigure the LSM so that the new port is allowed for this daemon.